# binary search for query results

Tags: java

While inserting from spreadsheet to database I have rows which are already existed.so i need to check existed rows before inserting. I am doing it in Java.
In the spread sheet I have:

```
     name
     a
     b
     c
     d
     b
```

Database dbo.emp has:

```
name id
 x     1
 y     2
 z     3
 d     4
```

where the row is repeated. To find out the repeated row I need to search the arraylist. so i query both excel and sql database. I put result obtained by querying the Excel sheet into arraylist namexcel. And result obtained by querying dbo.emp into arraylist namedb.
Now I need to search which are the existed rows from binary search.
I wrote query and stored like this:

```
        String ExcelQueryString2 = "select * from [Sheet1$]";
        ResultSet SpreadsheetValues = stmt2.executeQuery(ExcelQueryString2);
        List namexcel = new  ArrayList();
        while (SpreadsheetValues.next()) {
        namexcel.add(SpreadsheetValues.getString("name"));}

       String Querystring="SELECT Name from dbo.emp" 
      List namedb = new  ArrayList();
      ResultSet  rs = statement.executeQuery(Querystring);
         while(rs.next())
 {
        namedb .add(rs.getString("Name"));
   }
```

My questions:

1. How do I implement binary search for these arraylist?
2. How do I omit this row before insertion?
3. How do I remove the duplicate row which is existed in exceldatabase?

Please provide me the code snippets.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is about helping you when you have a problem, not doing all your work for you.

Comment: Also, please try adhering to at least basic English rules, capitalize properly ("I" especially) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

binary search requires you to maintain the `ArrayList` sorted, and use [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object%29) for searching.

You might want to concider using a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead - which guarantees no duplicates as part of its behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a `LinkedHashSet`, which ensures that no data is duplicated when data is added to it, whilst maintaining insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

You can create set implementation using both lists currently you have. Then you can use set difference method approach used in this link.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm

Actually you don't need go for a binary search. Before pass your list in to the binary search function you need to sort it. Which is a costly operation.